# ETag for GET in angular js - do i need to check on server-side

Tags: c#, angularjs, restangular, etag

I'm trying to implement etag for a GET request in angular JS, So far I've seen https://github.com/forforf/angular-etag 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-etag
and restangular(a complicated one but good). They all say it gives build in support for GET request, which i think means i don't have to code anything on server side(which is in c#.NET).

Am i right in assuming that, OR i've to use CacheCow or something to look for ETAG in the header and send 304 response.

Just a background, I've to use ETAG instead of cache(angular), so as to get latest data from server.

Comment: If you ever found out your solution please share

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a $http interceptor based solution, as I need it to work with all users of $http, and I can't just use a $http decorator like angular-http-etag does because e.g. $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader from Angular Translate uses $http and I want those calls to also be cached.

The solution below is written in Typescript and will store/retrieve the cache from localstorage, and will only keep the newest 25 cached items.

```
interface CacheObject {
    data: any;
    etag: string;
    index: number;
}

appModule.config(['$httpProvider', ($httpProvider) => {
    const cacheKey = 'add_your_unique_custom_localstorage_key_here';
    const cacheSize = 25;
    let index = 0;
    let cache: {[key: string]: CacheObject};

    const cacheString = localStorage.getItem(cacheKey);

    if (cacheString == null) {
        cache = Object.create(null);
    } else {
        cache = JSON.parse(cacheString);
        let cacheEntries = Object.entries(cache);

        for (const entry of cacheEntries) {
            // Find largest index
            const entryIndex = entry[1].index;
            if (entryIndex > index) {
                index = entryIndex;
            }
        }
        if (index > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
            // Reset cache if index gets larger than max safe int
            // This is kind of a theoretical problem
            cache = Object.create(null);
            cacheEntries = [];
            index = 0;
        }

        if (cacheEntries.length > cacheSize) {
            // Clean up cache once in a while. Only keep the 25 newest items
            const sortedCacheEntries = cacheEntries.sort((a, b) => {
                return b[1].index - a[1].index;
            });
            sortedCacheEntries.length = cacheSize;
            cache = sortedCacheEntries.reduce(
                (accum, [k, v]) => {
                    accum[k] = v;
                    return accum;
                },
                Object.create(null),
            );
        }
    }

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', ($q: ng.IQService) => {
        return {
            response: (response) => {
                const headers = response.headers();
                if (response.status === 200 && headers.etag) {
                    const cacheObject = {
                        data: response.data,
                        etag: headers.etag,
                        index: index++,
                    };
                    cache[response.config.url] = cacheObject;
                    localStorage.setItem(cacheKey, JSON.stringify(cache));
                }
                return response;
            },
            responseError: (response) => {
                if (response.status === 304) {
                    const cacheObject = cache[response.config.url];
                    if (cacheObject != null) {
                        const data = cacheObject.data;
                        const dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
                        const clonedData = JSON.parse(dataString);
                        response.data = clonedData;
                        // Will only recover if we set status to 200
                        response.status = 200;
                        return $q.resolve(response);
                    }
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            },
            request: (config) => {
                const cacheObject = cache[config.url];
                if (cacheObject != null) {
                    config.headers['If-None-Match'] = cacheObject.etag;
                }
                return config;
            },
        };
    }]);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of `angular-http-etag`, so I can only speak directly to the functionality of that module. It decorates Angular's `$http` service to allow you to specify requests that you'd like to cache. Here's the usage example I provide in the readme.md:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [
    'http-etag'
  ])
  .config(function (httpEtagProvider) {
    httpEtagProvider
      .defineCache('persistentCache', {
        cacheService: 'localStorage'
      })
  })

  .controller('MyCtrl', function ($http) {
    var self = this

    $http
      .get('/my_data.json', {
        etagCache: 'persistentCache'
      })
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config, itemCache) {
        // Modify the data from the server
        data._fullName = data.first_name + ' ' + data.last_name
        // Update the cache with the modified data
        itemCache.set(data)
        // Assign to controller property
        self.fullName = data._fullName
      })
      // Synchronous method called if request was previously cached
      .cached(function (data, status, headers, config, itemCache) {
        self.fullName = data._fullName
      })
      .error(function (data, status) {
        // 304: 'Not Modified'--Etag matched, cached data is fresh
        if (status != 304) alert('Request error')
      })
  })
```

The only thing that's required server-side is to make sure that the server is sending the `ETag` response header. You can find information about how to inspect response headers in Chrome here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading#view-details-for-a-single-resource

Answer (score 0):

Well, for certain server has to support issuing ETags and ASP.NET MVC or Web API do not by default. You have to use some form of output caching on the server.

One such project is Filip Woj's CacheOutput here

https://github.com/filipw/Strathweb.CacheOutput